# Upload files from Google Drive to GitHub Actions

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform

I want to upload a large file from my Google Drive account to git when doing GitHub Actions.

I have been working with this code:

```yaml
name: Run Tests

on: [push]

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Download dataset from Google Drive using gdown
      run: |
        pip install gdown
        gdown "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1O6xPLOt7o7G5K1P-GZPA5MC1wDVwN691" -O references_files.zip
        unzip references_files.zip -d /tmp/datasets
```

But I get this error:

```
Run curl -c ./cookie -s -L "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1O6xPLOt7o7G5K1P-GZPA5MC1wDVwN691" > /dev/null
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100  1642    0  1642    0     0  14393      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 14403
Archive:  references_files.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of references_files.zip or
        references_files.zip.zip, and cannot find references_files.zip.ZIP, period.
Error: Process completed with exit code 9.
```

I have read this approach:

```yaml
- name: Download from Google Drive
  uses: satackey/action-google-drive@v1
  with:
    skicka-tokencache-json: ${{ secrets.SKICKA_TOKENCACHE_JSON }}
    download-from: /path/to/download
    download-to: ./

    # For those who set up Google Drive API client ID and secret themselves
    google-client-id: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID }}
    google-client-secret: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET }}
```

from https://github.com/marketplace/actions/interact-with-google-drive#donwload but I don't understand this. I imaging I need to obtain Google Drive API Credentials but I don't know how to do this.

Is there any tutorial to follow that guide for the full task?